# Как в Юнити 2D менять изображение?

Tags: c#

Во первых стоит сказать что я не очень хорош в C# и поэтому не исключаю что ответ довольно простой. Тем не менее, в игре которую я делаю, я хочу чтобы иконка персонажа менялась относительно его здоровья (потеки крови, синяки и т.д)

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (health == 250)
        {
            if (Panel_good)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Instantiate(Panel_good);

            }

            if (health <= 250)
            {
                if (health <= 70)
                {
                    if (Panel_bad) // Чтобы проверить если она уже есть
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Instantiate(Panel_bad); //Чтобы вставить если нет
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Panel_medium)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Instantiate(Panel_medium);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибок нет, но изображения не появляются. Что мне стоит добавить чтобы это сработало? Заранее спасибо.